# How to find the set of values of a for which the line $y+x=0$ bisects the two chords from the point P?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

How to find the set of values of a for which the line $y+x=0$ bisects the two chords from the point $P(\frac{1+\sqrt{2a}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{2a}}{2})$ to the circle $2x^2+2y^2-(1+\sqrt{2a})x-(1-\sqrt{2a})y=0$ ?

Got stuck with this problem.Cant understand what does "two chords" mean here?And btw what should be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

The following is my interpretation of your problem. Hope it helps.

Let $1 + \sqrt {2a} = t$. Then, $1 – \sqrt {2a} = t’$, the corresponding surd conjugate.

Observations:-

(1) x + y = 0 is a line through O, the origin.

(2) Circle C (with center C) passes through O.

(3) P is on circle C.

(4) PC is a line through O.

Thus, we have the following diagram with

[image]

(1.1) PMH and PNK are the bisected chords.

(1.2) PM = MK and PN = NK.

(1.3) $\angle CMH = \angle CNk = 90^0$